# Why does Spring Cloud Stream throws a MessagingException after retries exhausted?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a consumer app receiving messages using Spring Cloud Stream. 
I have configured retry and DLQ but getting MessagingException after retries exceeded.

Here is my config:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group = myProcessingGroup
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.max-attempts=3
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.retryable-exceptions=<list of exception map>
```

What I am expecting is to retry 3 times and send the message to DLQ after retrying 3 times. It is weird to have a MessagingException in that case.

What do you think I am doing incorrect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your message is in DLQ. Have you looked?
Also, the exception that you see is simple logging

```
2019-08-26 14:49:01.456 ERROR 21139 --- [ocessingGroup-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler
```

. . .from Spring Integration LoggingHandler

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's true it is in DLQ. I was puzzled when I saw the error logs. I re-read the official docs many times. However, I couldn't read anywhere that these logs are subject to ignore. That's why I asked if there is more configuration to be done (or correct the ones I've made).

Comment: If you define your own `errorChannel` bean, the framework won't subscribe a logging error handler to it. The logging handler is only configured when an implicit `errorChannel` bean is defined.

Comment: I created a `ServiceActivator` with input channel value set as `errorChannel`. The logging handler is executed first and after that my errorChannel bean handler is run.

Comment: I found very useful info here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1510. Though it is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: 1) created an `errorChannel` bean 2) created a handler (service activator) to handle global errors on this channel. It works as I expected. Btw, I have still no idea why did you create a logging handler. What was the requirement? Thanks.